# Access AngularJS scope object using a different scope object as the key

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am iterating through an array of person objects using `ng-repeat` Say the array looks like this:

```
[{
  "display_name": "John Smith",
  "status": "part-time",
  "bio": "I am a person. I do people stuff.",
}, {
  "display_name": "Jane Doe",
  "status": "full-time",
  "bio": "I am yet another person.",
}, ...]
```

Meanwhile, I have another `number_list` object that looks like this (note the uppercase):

```
{
  "JOHN SMITH": 12,
  "JANE DOE": 34,
  ...
}
```

In the HTML, I am able to interpolate from each person object like so:

```
<p>
  Person Name: {{ person.display_name }}
  Person Bio: {{ person.bio }}
  ...
</p>
```

But I'd also like to interpolate from the second object, accessing the value where the key matches the person object I'm on, like so:

```
<p>
  ...
  Person Number: {{ number_list['{{ person.display_name | uppercase }}'] }}
</p>
```

I am using the EMCAScript Bracket notation rather than the dot notation to specify the key, because of the spaces in the key names of `number_list` (e.g.`"JOHN SMITH"`) but I get nothing out of that interpolation.

I have confirmed that if I type in a name e.g. `{{ number_list['JOHN SMITH'] }}` that I am able to interpolate the value -- `12` in this example. This means the issue doesn't have to do with scope or anything like that as far as I can tell.

Comment: You need *either* the `.` or the `[ ]` — not both.

Comment: @Pointy thanks for that, that was an error in transcribing my issue here, the period isn't really there in the code. I've edited my post to remove it.

Comment: Still doesn't work unfortunately...

Comment: Nested interpolation with double curly braces (`{{ }}`) is not supported by the AngularJS framework. If you want to run more complex code, you should make it a controller method and call the method from your view.

Answer (score 0):

Nested interpolation with double curly braces (`{{ }}`) is not supported by the AngularJS framework. If you want to run more complex code, you should make it a controller method and call the method from your view.

```
<p ng-repeat="person in persons">
  ...
  ̶P̶e̶r̶s̶o̶n̶ ̶N̶u̶m̶b̶e̶r̶:̶ ̶{̶{̶ ̶n̶u̶m̶b̶e̶r̶_̶l̶i̶s̶t̶[̶'̶{̶{̶ ̶p̶e̶r̶s̶o̶n̶.̶d̶i̶s̶p̶l̶a̶y̶_̶n̶a̶m̶e̶ ̶|̶ ̶u̶p̶p̶e̶r̶c̶a̶s̶e̶ ̶}̶}̶'̶]̶ ̶}̶}̶
  Person Number: {{ ::personNumber(person.display_name) }}
</p>
```

```js
$scope.personNumber = function(name) {
    return $scope.number_list[name.toUpperCase()];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `filter` to `personNumber` for an object:

```
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope){
   $scope.persons = [...];

   $scope.number_list = [...];
})     

app.filter("personNumber", function(){
    return function(array, name){
      return array[name.toUpperCase()];
    }
})

<p ng-repeat="person in persons">
  ...
  Person Number: {{person.display_name | personNumber: number_list}}
</p>
```